# help verifying battery schematic

Tags: batteries, wiring, laptop

The diagram below is for wiring up a 6 cell laptop battery. Visually, there are four batteries in one row, and two batteries in a second row. The cells are the usual 3.7v 18650 cells. I am pretty sure I managed to diagram the connections as they were in the old battery, but I feel like there's something missing.

The battery casing says we should be shooting for  **11.1V** and 5200mAh (though that depends on the mAh rating of the individual cells, so ignore that). I know some batteries are 14V units, but this one says it should be 11.1V. So bear that in mind.

[image]

The lines that are not black are monitoring wires. So if you can take a look at the black lines and tell me whether it all is as it should, that would be appreciated.

UPDATE: this is the diagram as I expect it to be with three sets of parallel two's with the one set awkwardly hugging the other two:
[image]

Comment: You've got something wrong. It's probably 3S2P - three series, two strings in parallel. You've got all sorts of short circuits with your drawing. Redraw it and number the cells for ease of discussion and show the battery output (the feed to the laptop). The left and rightmost cells may be in parallel but can't be connected to both sides of the four in the middle.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I re-checked 3 times, but it doesn't make sense. Connect three sets of two together is what I expected to be doing cause that would give me around 11.1V (3.7 * 3). Let me see what I can do with the diagram.

Comment: Can you give us a sharp, cropped photo?

Comment: Sure. Let me see.

Comment: The battery is already taken apart. The cells and connections I mean. I have added a new diagram of what I think the thing should be wired like. I can clearly make out three parallel sets, as well as a monitoring wire from each pair's positive side, and one on the right-most pair's negative side.